# sql job to run every certain time and execute a console application

Tags: c#, console-application, sql-job

I am trying to write a SQL job to run every 10 minutes and to execute a console application that I wrote in C#.

It would be really helpful if someone could help.

Comment: Why not use a Windows Scheduled Task instead?

Comment: Yeah.. Why not a Scheduled task? A scheduled task lets you schedule running and exe periodically

Comment: Please provide the brand, version and edition of SQL that you are trying to use.

Comment: am not using windows scheduled task cause its something related to falling of the server that my console application is on. thanks for the suggestion, I was thinking about, but its not good for my case.

Comment: It would be really helpful if you detailed what you have tried to do and what problem you actually have. It is not clear from your post what your problem is since you did not ask a question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is a SQL Server Agent Job, with a CmdExec step (which can execute a windows command line).  This is explained here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190264.aspx

If security is a concern, it can be secured through the use of a SQL Agent Proxy definition.  This is explained here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189064(SQL.105).aspx

Comment: can you provide me with an example it would be a great help.

Comment: Pointers to doc and examples provided.